# ssh key authentication without passphrase: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed

Tags: authentication, ssh, pem, key-pair, passphrase

I setup the key-pair authentication. I generated the private key without the passphrase. One client establishes the connection to the server without any input prompt. But other client always asks for the passphrase for the private key. Trying the verbose mode I get:

```
. . . . . . . . . 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: .ssh/priv.key
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '.ssh/priv.key':
debug1: Next authentication method: password
. . . . . . . . .
```

But I can successfully read this key file:

```
$ ls -la .ssh/priv.key
-rw------- 1 xxxxx xxxxx 1834 May 18 14:49 .ssh/priv.key
$
$ cat .ssh/priv.key
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.......
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
$
```

Comment: Hi @igortche, can you show what you have done, please? a [mcve] will be helpful to anyone who will be willing to help you.

Answer (score 0):

When I converted the private key to the RSA format then I've got the success.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.......
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```